# Preparing plugin for $.plugin() usage instead of $(selector).plugin()

Tags: jquery

Simply:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.plugin = function()
    {
        // results in error
        // when called like
        // $.plugin();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The error is (copied from Chrome console):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    } has no method 'plugin'
```

What rules I have to follow in order to make my plugin work without the element selection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply assign the function directly to `$.plugin`:

```
(function($){
    $.plugin = function()
    {
        // ...
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Of course `this` won't refer to selected elements anymore, but to `jQuery` itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have announced a plugin, as a method of object $.fn and trying to gain access to the plugin as a method of Object jQuery

Comment: **1)** If you specify a function jQuery.fn, then it will work with the elements found in $ () function. The context of this function will contain the selected items;  **2)** If you specify a function in terms of jQuery, then it can be accessed only through a global object jQuery. In this case, the context of the function will point to the global object is window

Answer (score 0):

Keep jQuery's conventions and prefer using it in this way:

```
$(this).plugin()
```